# How to save and restore a lstm trained model in Tensorflow using Saver?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have saved a trained LSTM model and I want to restore the prediction to use it in testing. I was trying to follow [this post](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/). But I am getting errors. Here is what I tried:

```
x = tf.placeholder('tf.float32', [None, input_vec_size, 1])
y = tf.placeholder('tf.float32')


def recurrent_neural_network(x):
    layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes])),
             'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}     
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
    x = tf.split(x, input_vec_size, 0)

    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer['weights']), layer['biases'])

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = recurrent_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        Training ...
        saver.save(sess, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'my_test_model'))
```

After that, in the training phase I am trying

```
def test_neural_network(input_data):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model.meta')
        new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
        prediction = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("prediction:0")

        Calculate features from input_data ...
        result = sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: features}), 1))
```

But this throws the following error:

> KeyError: "The name 'prediction:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'prediction', does not exist in the graph."

Then I tried adding :
`tf.add_to_collection('prediction', prediction)` before saving and replacing by `prediction = tf.get_collection('prediction')[0]` after restoring. But this gives me the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float and shape [?,34,1]
>        [[Node: Placeholder_2 = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,34,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I know for the first error, I am supposed to assign a name in order to restore but `prediction` is not a tensorflow variable. I went through few previous posts and articles but unable to come up with a working solution. So, my questions are:

1. Am I doing something conceptually wrong? If so, what?
2. If not, is there an implementation error? And how do I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could save my trained model at last and so posting an answer in case anyone comes across this question. I did not get a solution for the exact problem but I could build and save my model using `tflearn`. In order to train and store:

```
model = tflearn.DNN(lstm_model(n_classes, input_vec_size))
model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_set=(test_x, test_y), n_epoch=20,
          show_metric=True, snapshot_epoch=True, run_id='lstm_model')
model.save("../Models/lstm_model")
```

And later, to restore:

```
model.load(filepath+"lstm_model")
```

This seemed to be a far easier way to work with the model, and provides a compact and novel way to do the same task which I posted in the question.